# Is there difference default value between libmysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php 7.3 application who behaves differently in local and in production.

I have a User table with a column "agence" like this

**agence varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,**

In local mode, when i save a new user without specified the "agence" field i have this error message (which seems normal to me)

**Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'agence' doesn't have a default value**

But when i save the same things in production, i can save without error.

The columns are declared in same way in local and production.

The only difference i see is the version of libmysql

- libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev (in local mode)
- libmysql - 5.6.43  (in production mode)

This is the result of EXPLAIN users in local

Field   Type    Null    Key     Default     Extra
id  int(11)     NO  PRI     NULL    auto_increment
nom     varchar(100)    NO      NULL
prenom  varchar(100)    NO      NULL
agence varchar(255)     NO      NULL

And in **production**

Field   Type    Null    Key     Default     Extra
id  int(11)     NO  PRI     NULL    auto_increment
nom     varchar(100)    NO      NULL
prenom  varchar(100)    NO      NULL
agence varchar(255)     NO      NULL

This is the request

```
SQL Query: INSERT INTO `db`.`users` (`nom`, `prenom`) VALUES ('AAAAPETIT', 'robert' )
```

I don't understand why in production server, mysql seems to be more permissive ? is there an adjustment to be made ?

Comment: How do you check in PHP that the query was executed successfully? How do you handle MySQL errors in your PHP script? Are there actually rows saved in the production MySQL server? If that is the case, what is the value of the `agence` column?

Comment: Because the user is saved in production mode. The "agence" column is empty without "NULL" value and without "empty string"

Comment: What is your `sql_mode` on your test server and production server? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46600333/mysql-not-getting-an-error-when-updating-a-not-null-column-to-null

Comment: The sql_mode in production is empty.
The sql_mode in local is :
STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTIO

Comment: There you have it, strict mode is missing, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46600333/mysql-not-getting-an-error-when-updating-a-not-null-column-to-null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference was the sql_mode.

I showed the sql_mode like this

> SELECT @@sql_mode

And to modify like this:

> SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';

Thanks for you help